# How do I offset Pandas dayofyear so start date is 1st October not 1st January?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have the following dataframe:

How do I offset Pandas dayofyear so start date is 1st October not 1st January

[image]

In this case, I want the year to be from 1st October to 30th Sep, and it would need to take into account leap years.

Below is an example of how I want the output, with the day of the year column the only variable.

[image]

here is the dataframe in table form:

```
           Day  stock  dayofyear  weekday  month  year  leapyear
0   24/09/2019     10        267        1      9  2019     False
1   25/09/2019     10        268        2      9  2019     False
2   26/09/2019     11        269        3      9  2019     False
3   27/09/2019     12        270        4      9  2019     False
4   28/09/2019     14        271        5      9  2019     False
5   29/09/2019     14        272        6      9  2019     False
6   30/09/2019     15        273        0      9  2019     False
7   01/10/2019     16        274        1     10  2019     False
8   02/10/2019     17        275        2     10  2019     False
9   03/10/2019     18        276        3     10  2019     False
10  04/10/2019     19        277        4     10  2019     False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use:**

```
df['Day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Day'], dayfirst=True)

base_year = np.where(df['month'].ge(10), df['year'], df['year'].sub(1))
base_date = pd.to_datetime(base_year, format='%Y') + pd.DateOffset(months=9)
df['dayofyear'] = (df['Day'] - base_date).dt.days.add(1)
```

---

**Details:**

Using [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) convert the `Day` column to pandas datetime series, then use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) along with [`Series.gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) and [`Series.sub`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) to compute the `base_year` for each date in `Day` column.

```
print(base_year)
array([2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019])
```

Use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to convert the `base_year` to pandas datetime series and add a offset of `9 months` so that the `base_date` starts from `1 October`.

```
print(base_date)
DatetimeIndex(['2018-10-01', '2018-10-01', '2018-10-01', '2018-10-01',
               '2018-10-01', '2018-10-01', '2018-10-01', '2019-10-01',
               '2019-10-01', '2019-10-01', '2019-10-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Subtract the `Day` column from this `base_date` and use [`Series.dt.days`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html) to compute the `dayofyear`:

```
print(df)
          Day  stock  dayofyear  weekday  month  year  leapyear
0  2019-09-24     10        359        1      9  2019     False
1  2019-09-25     10        360        2      9  2019     False
2  2019-09-26     11        361        3      9  2019     False
3  2019-09-27     12        362        4      9  2019     False
4  2019-09-28     14        363        5      9  2019     False
5  2019-09-29     14        364        6      9  2019     False
6  2019-09-30     15        365        0      9  2019     False
7  2019-10-01     16          1        1     10  2019     False
8  2019-10-02     17          2        2     10  2019     False
9  2019-10-03     18          3        3     10  2019     False
10 2019-10-04     19          4        4     10  2019     False
```